# Query Object Pattern (Design Pattern)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to implement a Query Object Pattern in Java for my customizable search interface (of a webapp I'm writing).

Does anybody know where I can get an example/tutorial of Query Object Pattern (Martin Fowler's QoP)?

Thanks in Advance

**ADDITION** How to add a Query Pattern to an existing DAO pattern?

Comment: Note that Hibernate has a nice Criteria API (JPA 2.0 also has a typesafe criteria API now).

Comment: What I'm gathering is that I should move to Hibernate then.

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265290/query-object-implementation-examples

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word "pattern" in the "Query Object Pattern" is (IMHO) misplaced. It's not a real design pattern. The "Query Object" is just another example of the [Interpreter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern). The legacy [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) and the modern [JPA2 Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html) are an excellent examples which combines it with the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

As to your question:

> *How to add a Query Pattern to an existing DAO pattern?*

I would recommend to have a look at [JPA2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a C# implementation for NHibernate here: https://github.com/shaynevanasperen/NHibernate.Sessions.Operations.

It works by using an interface like this:

```
public interface IDatabases
{
    ISessionManager SessionManager { get; }

    T Query<T>(IDatabaseQuery<T> query);
    T Query<T>(ICachedDatabaseQuery<T> query);

    void Command(IDatabaseCommand command);
    T Command<T>(IDatabaseCommand<T> command);
}
```

Given a POCO entity class like this:

```
class Database1Poco
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can build query objects like this:

```
class Database1PocoByProperty1 : DatabaseQuery<Database1Poco>
{
    public override Database1Poco Execute(ISessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        return sessionManager.Session.Query<Database1Poco>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Property1 == Property1);
    }

    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

And then use them like this:

```
var database1Poco = _databases.Query(new Database1PocoByProperty1 { Property1 = 1 });
```

You could port that to Java if you like it.

Here are some other examples:

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/
http://www.mrdustpan.com/command-query-objects-with-dapper#disqus_thread
http://crosscuttingconcerns.com/CommandQuery-Object-pattern

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment instead?

Comment: I don't think so. It directly answers the question by providing example code.