# Query object implementation examples

Tags: architectural-patterns

Can anyone recommend good tutorial, implementation or sample code on Query object pattern usage, in C#(Java...)?

I haven't found much with google.

Answer (score 4):

With LINQ being almost everywhere, are you sure you need to reimplement the [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html)?

Basically, you can treat all classes from [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) to be a good implementation of a Query Object pattern.

Comment: I tend to agree with this. Can anyone give me a reason why not to use LINQ instead of an implementation of the Query Object Pattern?

Comment: @Ozzy maybe because it isnt supported by his database provider??

Comment: over WCF (if you are stuck with a non supporting binding)

Answer (score 3):

From Chad Myers:

*Part 1:* http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/08/01/query-objects-with-the-repository-pattern.aspx

Comment: *Part 2:* http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/08/02/query-objects-with-repository-pattern-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Martin Fowler's Query Object Pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html). Get his book ["Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa), you'll find sample implementation there.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a nice query object library for NHibernate. Check it out here: https://github.com/shaynevanasperen/NHibernate.Sessions.Operations