# NHibernate and repositories design pattern

Tags: nhibernate

I've been working with NHibernate for quite a while and have come to realize that my architecture might be a bit...dated. This is for an NHibernate library that is living behind several apps that are related to each other.

First off, I have a DomainEntity base class with an ID and an EntityID (which is a guid that I use when I expose an item to the web or through an API, instead of the internal integer id - I think I had a reason for it at one point, but I'm not sure it's really valid now). I have a Repository base class where T inherits from DomainEntity that provides a set of generalized search methods. The inheritors of DomainEntity may also implement several interfaces that track things like created date, created by, etc., that are largely a log for the most recent changes to the object. I'm not fond of using a repository pattern for this, but it wraps the logic of setting those values when an object is saved (provided that object is saved through the repository and not saved as part of saving something else).

I would like to rid myself of the repositories. They don't make me happy and really seem like clutter these days, especially now that I'm not querying with hql and now that I can use extension methods on the Session object. But how do I hook up this sort of functionality cleanly? Let's assume for the purposes of discussion that I have something like structuremap set up and capable of returning an object that exposes context information (current user and the like), what would be a good flexible way of providing this functionality outside of the repository structure? Bonus points if this can be hooked up along with a convention-based mapping setup (I'm looking into replacing the XML files as well).

Answer (score 0):

If you dislike the fact that repositories can become bloated over time then you may want to use something like [Query Objects](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html).

The basic idea is that you break down a single query into an individual object that you can then apply it to the database.

Some example implementation links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265290/query-object-implementation-examples).

Comment: The query side is fairly straightforward to handle, either via query objects or through extension methods (I'm not sure which of these I like better - I'm going to have to experiment). If I can just get the command side figured out, I can get rid of the repositories in their entirety.